# How to convert image file into integer array in java?

Tags: java, image

How can you convert an image file  (.png in this instance) into a 3d (one coordinate for width of image, one for weight and one for the integers showing Red, green and blue values) integer or byte array?

Comment: Your title says "how to", but then you specify that you simply want to know if it's possible. Which is it?

Comment: Changed it. I meant that I wanted the method of doing it. Sorry if i didn't make it clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to convert image file into integer array..?

See:

- [`BufferedImage.getData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData%28%29)
- [`Raster.getPixels(int,int,int,int,int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#getPixels%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5b%5d%29)